# jQuery validation plugin - no error messages instead custom backgrounds

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). The form which is being validated has custom background images for the text input fields, so instead of showing an error message for invalid fields I would like to change the background image. Making things a bit trickier is that the background image for the fields is on a different `div` absolutely positioned behind the text field (which has a transparent background and no border). I will spare going into the reasons for this design decision here (it's related to margins within the text field) but I thought it should be mentioned since it is critical to this question.

Therefore, I have two questions:

1. How can I stop the display of the error messages all-together?
2. How can I instead tell the validation plugin if, for example, the name field (e.g. `<input id=name ... />`) is invalid then it should change the background for the relevant div (e.g. `<div id=name-bg... ></div>`)?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: I think it's better for you to start creating your own validator, it isn't that tricky and you'll also achieve exactly what you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How can I stop the display of the
>   error messages all-together?

You can accomplish this by using the `showErrors` option of the validate plugin:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
           /* Custom error-handling code here */
        }
    }
});
```

The `errorList` argument is a list of objects, each containing an `element` property that is the DOM element with the error.

> How can I instead tell the validation
>   plugin if, for example, the name field
>   is invalid then it should change the
>   background for the relevant div?

Using the `showErrors` option and the `errorList` argument detailed above, you could accomplish this like this:

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        var i, length = errorList.length;
        var el;

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            el = errorList[i].element;
            /* Build up a selector based on the element containing and error's id:*/
            $("#" + el.id + "-bg").show() // <-- write code against this selector
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a proof-of-concept: http://jsfiddle.net/vD5cQ/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Worked perfectly :)