# jQuery validate - alter css of invalid elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery.validate plugin but I would like to change the background color of the input field that has failed rather than displaying a message? Is there anything like this already built in to the plugin or will I need to add something to make it work?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules: {
        YourName: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
//I want to highlight the failed element here by changing the background color
    submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.post('projectform.php', $("#myForm").serialize(), function(data)
        {
          $('#myDiv').html(data);       
        });
      }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this link

[jQuery validation plugin - no error messages instead custom backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577895/jquery-validation-plugin-no-error-messages-instead-custom-backgrounds)

you can change ".error" class to customize your input field

Answer (score 3):

try setting custom functions like

```
$("#myForm").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                element.addClass('errorClass');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
               $(element).removeClass('errorClass');
            }
}
```

where errorClass is a class added to the inputs when it's not valid